# Laravel Log Files - Permissions Issue

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I had used Laravel Forge to spin up a server, and adjusted some of the provisioning to my needs.

Forge creates a sudo-privileged nginx user named `forge`.

I made a user called `deploy` with sudo privileges, and changed nginx to use this user.

The app functions fine however, anytime Laravel writes to a log file (laravel.log, my-custom-log.log, etc) it says the user is `forge` and the group is `deploy`.

Any ideas on why Laravel may still be defaulting to that User even though nginx is using a different user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that PHP-FPM was defaulting to to user:group forge:forge.  I was able to change this in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`